# Does Quarkus supports CSRF attack protection on GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, csrf, quarkus, smallrye

I am not sure if Quarkus GraphQL has any build-in CSRF attack protection.

Usually, CSRF attack has to do with posting html forms e.g. for content types:
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

But, there are scenarios that `application/json` can also be vulnerable, if for example you disable the CORS.

As I understood, here: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-csrf-prevention
quarkus prevents the "form posting" scenarios.
Additionally, in the same page we read:

```
@POST
    @Path("/users")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String postJson(User user) {
        return user.name;
    }
...

--> [ POST json request to /user, CSRF token verification is not needed ]
```

and my assumption here is that quarkus prevents also this and we don't need to do anything else.

Is my assumption correct or I miss something?

If yes, does the same CSRF security solution applied to GraphQL as well?

Thank you

What I did:

I set up the `quarkus-csrf-reactive` in my application along with `quarkus-smallrye-graphql` and created a `@Mutation` resource. I was expecting some sort of CSRF prevention cookies to be exchanged.

```
@GraphQLApi
public class TestResource {
  @Mutation
  public Uni<String> testing2(int id) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item("DONE " + id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This CSRF feature is only applicable to HTTP form requests, the comment about JSON there in the example is related to the fact that a JAX-RS endpoint might have not only form related updates in which case it is possible to configure the feature not to enforce the CSRF cookie/token match on such paths.
CORS feature can help with other cases such as JSON uploads, etc.
I believe GraphQL is using WebSockets, CSRF feature will no work there

Answer (score 0):

The outcome is:

Since there is no other way (e.g. through an "http form post") to call the GraphQL resource, then yes, I am considering the GraphQL with CORS safe against CSRF attacks.
The only way to call GraphQL (mutation/queries) is through Javascript AJAX and all modern browsers are taking into consideration the CORS restrictions and will block any AJAX calls from unknown domains (e.g. CSRF attack).

The more detailed discussion is here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/31860